# GDataCalendar.h is not found when I try to archive

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api, gdata, gdata-api

My project is connected with Google Calendar by using GData API. I test everything work fine in Debug mode on both simulator and device. But when I archive in order to create an adHoc. It give me an error that say GDataCalendar.h is not found. Please help.

I checked, in my project target-->Build Setting-->Header Search Path

- In Debug mode, I have ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Headers
- In Release Mode,I have ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Headers
- In Distribution mode, I have ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Headers

Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After, 5 hrs of searching I finally found a solution for this problem. I just created new group and copy all the headers (DO NOT set any target). That's it. Hope this can save someone's 5 hrs.